# \pageref refers to second to last page of document part with floats cleared by \clearpage instead of last page

Tags: floats, page-numbering, lastpage, clearpage, pageref

I have a document where I input the main part via `\input{}`, add a `label` to refer to for the page numbering (similar to how the `lastpage`-package works) and use a `\clearpage` to start the appendix on the next page. For the appendix I actually use the `lastpage`-package for the page numbering. The main part is numbered with arabic numbers while the appendix is numbered with roman numerals.

When the floats of the main part are already cleared/set when the `label` is set everything works as intended. In my last document I had floats which weren't cleared before the clearpage command and now the page counter refers to the page before the actual last page due to it only containing floats.

As can be seen in the MWE the page numbering on the second page is [image] where instead of the 1 should be a 2 (the total number of pages in the main part/part before the appendix).

I tried to use `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins`-package which produces the same exact result as with `\clearpage`.
I also tried to use the `\afterpage`-package but that changed all page numbers to roman numerals.

What kind of worked was moving the label after the `\clearpage` and adding another `\newpage` or `\clearpage` after it. But that added an additional (apart from headers/footers) blank page.

Is there a way to make the page numbering as intended? So in the MWE on the second page there should be 2/2 instead of 2/1.

EDIT: Moving the label inside the last float could solve the problem for this specific document, but I want to fix the template I'm using so I (hopefully) won't have to deal with this problem in the future.

EDIT 2: Using the `pageslts`-package recommended by @cfr I got it working. However if I include a preamble with its own page numbering scheme, set `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for the titlepage and edit the `lastpageref` to `pagesLTS.arabic.2` I get multiple `! Output routine didn't use all of \box255`-errors. If I use an otherwise unused page numbering scheme, e.g. `\pagenumbering{alph}`, or use the page numbering scheme from the preamble I don't get such errors. See new MWE after the old one. Did I misread the documentation for pageslts or why does this error occur?

EDIT 3: The [Followup question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701111/how-to-avoid-error-when-using-pagesltls-with-multiple-uses-pagenumberingara) by @cfr condenses the problem from EDIT 2 to the essentials. I thought my problem might be related to the `input`-commands or the footers so I included what I deemed necessary in the new MWE.

Old/Original MWE:

```
\documentclass[footheight=27.2pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
%\usepackage{placeins}

\newpairofpagestyles{MainPartStyle}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \cfoot*{\normalfont \thepage{}\ /\ \pageref*{MainPartLastPage}}
}
\newpairofpagestyles{AppendixStyle}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \cfoot*{\normalfont \thepage{}\ /\ \pageref*{LastPage}}
}

\begin{filecontents}{MainPart.tex}
\section{Section} \label{secSection}
This text gets written to \texttt{MainPart.tex}.

\subsection{Subsection 1} \label{secSubsection1}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=0.7\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{I am a figure}
\end{figure}


\subsection{Subsection 2} \label{secSubsection2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

\pagestyle{MainPartStyle}
\input{MainPart}
\label{MainPartLastPage}
\clearpage      % my inital solution
%\FloatBarrier
%\afterpage{\FloatBarrier}
%\afterpage{\clearpage}

\section{Appendix}
\pagestyle{AppendixStyle} \label{secAppendix}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

New MWE for `pageslts` `! Output routine didn't use all of \box255`-error:

```
\documentclass[footheight=27.2pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage[alphMult=ab,AlphMulti=AB,romanMult,RomanMulti]{pageslts}


\newpairofpagestyles{MainPartStyle}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \cfoot*{\normalfont \thepage{}\ /\ \lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic}}
    %\cfoot*{\normalfont \thepage{}\ /\ \lastpageref*{pagesLTS.arabic.2}}   % does not work
}
\newpairofpagestyles{PreambleStyle}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \cfoot*{\normalfont \thepage{}\ /\ \lastpageref*{pagesLTS.roman}}
}
\newpairofpagestyles{AppendixStyle}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \cfoot*{\normalfont \thepage{}\ /\ \lastpageref*{pagesLTS.Roman}}
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{MainPart.tex}
\section{Section} \label{secSection}
This text gets written to \texttt{MainPart.tex}.

\subsection{Subsection 1} \label{secSubsection1}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=0.5\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{I am a figure}
\end{figure}


\subsection{Subsection 2} \label{secSubsection2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Titlepage.tex}
\renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{10cm}
        Title
        \vfill
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}     % does not work, even with changes to \lastpageref in the pagestyle
%\pagenumbering{alph}       % works
\pagenumbering{roman}       % works
\setcounter{page}{0}
\input{titlepage}
\newpage

\pagestyle{PreambleStyle}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagestyle{MainPartStyle}
\input{MainPart}
\clearpage

\section{Appendix}
\pagestyle{AppendixStyle}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: you could put a label also in the float and then use the larger number. Or record the absolute page number of the appendix and use the number -1.

Comment: The easy solution is to move `\label{MainPartLastPage}` inside the figure, since it winds up on the last page.  Note that you have to manually delete the old version of MainPart.tex every time you make a change.  BTW, `\afterpage` will not run on a float page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo or let `pageslts` insert labels for you?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought about that, but that would be a fix specific to this document whereas I want to fix the template I'm using.